# OpenTok:GlobalExceptionHandler:error OT.exception :: title: Unable to Publish (1500) msg: GetUserMedia +0ms

Tags: filestack

I have implemented the File stack using Iframe In local code it's working fine when I hosting my project IIS server. It's coming on an error

1. OpenTok:Publisher:error onStreamAvailableError OT_NOT_SUPPORTED: A constraint specified is not supported by the browser. (getUserMedia error: NotSupportedError) +0ms
2. OpenTok:GlobalExceptionHandler:error OT.exception :: title: Unable to Publish (1500) msg: GetUserMedia +0ms
3. OpenTok:Session:error 1500 +0ms Session.publish :: A constraint specified is not supported by the browser. (getUserMedia error: NotSupportedError)

Comment: Hi Baranidharan, have you solved the issue :)